# Setting xticks in pandas bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I came across this different behaviour in the third example plot below. Why am I able to correctly edit the x-axis' ticks with `pandas` `line()` and `area()` plots, but not with `bar()`? What's the best way to fix the (general) third example?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(73,145,1)
y = np.cos(x)

df = pd.Series(y,x)
ax1 = df.plot.line()
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2.5))
plt.show()

ax2 = df.plot.area(stacked=False)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2.5))
plt.show()

ax3 = df.plot.bar()
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2.5))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Problem:

The bar plot is meant to be used with categorical data. Therefore the bars are not actually at the positions of `x` but at positions `0,1,2,...N-1`. The bar labels are then adjusted to the values of `x`.
If you then put a tick only on every tenth bar, the second label will be placed at the tenth bar etc. The result is

[image]

You can see that the bars are actually positionned at integer values starting at 0 by using a normal ScalarFormatter on the axes:

```
ax3 = df.plot.bar()
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2.5))
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

[image]

Now you can of course define your own fixed formatter like this

```
n = 10
ax3 = df.plot.bar()
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(n))
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(n/4.))
seq =  ax3.xaxis.get_major_formatter().seq
ax3.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter([""]+seq[::n]))
```

[image]

which has the drawback that it starts at some arbitrary value.

#### Solution:

I would guess the best general solution is not to use the pandas plotting function at all (which is anyways only a wrapper), but the matplotlib `bar` function directly:

```
fig, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.bar(df.index, df.values, width=0.72)
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax3.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(2.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. :)

Comment: got me close, but when I use your last example, the numbers are not scaled properly, only the ticks. Instead of 70, 80, ... I see 70, 71, 72 as if it is increasing them by only 1 only instead of what the multiplicator tells it

Comment: @n3rd One cannot know what you are doing, so if it is a real problem you face, ask a comple question including [mcve] about it.