# Pandas bar plot x axis stuck on wrong column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bar-chart

I want to plot a bar plot from pandas dataframe and have a reasonable amount of xticks.

My dataframe (data) looks like this:

```
0  Channel  Counts  Energy [keV]
0        1       0         -0.02
0        2       0          0.01
0        3       0          0.04 
...
2     2044       2         58.81
1     2045       1         58.83
[2048 rows x 4 columns]
```

I'm plotting the bar plot with x = data["Energy [keV]"] and height = data["Counts"] and whatever I try I get either:

- All 2048 energy values with labels which become a jumbled mess
- First 50 (for example) energy values jumbled together at the beginning of the x-axis

Basically the plot is plotting the position of the bars right (using the energy values) and when I try to manipulate ticks, or add a vertical line it always uses 0 to 2048 x axis.

What I get is that: [plot with jumbled values (too many ticks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHhDl.png)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

tmp = {'Channel': np.arange(1, 2049, 1),'Energy [keV]': np.arange(1, 2049, 1),
       'Counts': np.random.rand(2048)*1000}
data = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
data['Energy [keV]'] = -0.048 + 0.029*data['Channel']

fig4 = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
ax4 = fig4.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

data.plot.bar(x = "Energy [keV]", y = "Counts", width=1, ax=ax4, align='center')
ax4.vlines(x=25.0, ymin = ylim_min, ymax = ylim_max, color = 'darkred')
```

I tried couple of solutions including converting the columns into numpy arrays, changing dataframe index, xaxis.set_ticks, xaxis.set_major_formatter... but something is always wrong.

I want to have nice, round ticks like 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, and when I make vline at x=25.0 that it would actually be at the value of 25.0. In the code I created a random number of counts so the snippet will be easier to recreate.

Comment: You can set the tick marks manually, or you can chose to bin the rows by energy (basically, creating a histogram instead of a barplot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

> A bar plot is a plot that presents **categorical** data with rectangular
> bars with lengths proportional to the values that they represent

It tries to show all of the the "categories". The problem is, it treats each of the observation as single category - so if the observations are not evenly distributed across x axis (and in your example, they are not), the the x axis will be distorted. To illustrate it, if we modify your data:

```py
data['Energy [keV]'] = data['Energy [keV]'] + (data['Energy [keV]'] > 50)*2
```

And plot it using bar, you won't see anything suspicious:

[image]

While the actual data looks like this:

[image]

You of course can try fix it somehow by [setting x_ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478659/setting-xticks-in-pandas-bar-plot), but it is intended behaviour - maybe think of some different chart type, for example:

```py
data.plot.line(x = "Energy [keV]", y = "Counts",ax=ax4, linewidth =0.1)
ax4.fill_between(x = data["Energy [keV]"], y1 = data["Counts"], y2=0)
ax4.set_xlim(data["Energy [keV]"].min(), data["Energy [keV]"].max())
ax4.set_ylim(0, data["Counts"].max()*1.1)
ax4.axvline(x=25.0, color = 'darkred')
```

[image: Plot]

or:

```py
markerline, stemlines, baseline = ax4.stem(data["Energy [keV]"], data["Counts"], markerfmt=' ')
plt.setp(stemlines, 'linewidth', 0.4)
ax4.set_xlim(data["Energy [keV]"].min(), data["Energy [keV]"].max())
ax4.set_ylim(0, data["Counts"].max()*1.1)
ax4.axvline(x=25.0, color = 'darkred')
```

[image: plot 2]

Comment: Thanks - the other plots work as they should

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ax4.bar(data["Energy [keV]"], data["Counts"], width=1, align='center')`?

Comment: Tried that, still the same problem, but thanks ^^